# Recommended Method to Deploy Different Configurations

Tags: php, configuration-files

within a PHP project, what would be the recommended way of creating configuration files and reading them within the app; configuration files that would be deployed with different content to staging vs. production servers for instance.

Comment: This is too broad of a question for the SO format and also likely opinion based. There are any number of configuration management approaches and tools out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend looking at how the Symfony project injects Parameters for different systems. [Symfony's Config Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current//components/config/introduction.html) can be installed as a standalone library and integrated with most projects.

A default parameters.yml.dist is distributed with the codebase but upon system install customised parameters.yml can either be generated manually on the command line or automatically using a deployment process. This avoids holding sensitive and mutable infrastructure information in your codebase.

[Symfony Introduction to Parameters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/parameters.html)

[Symfony Config Parameters Best Practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html)

Combining this with a docker & vagrant setup will enable configuration options to be mirrored across your environment platforms (production, development, testing). A good tutorial on doing this for PHP frameworks can be found [here](https://blog.vandenbrand.org/2016/02/03/developing-symfony-applications-with-docker-series-part-i-getting-started/).